# Does Flexi-auth support third-party login? if yes how to do?

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I'm using **Flexi-auth** library for user authentication with codeigniter, 
General login is working properly.
Does Flexi-auth support third-party(google/yahoo) login? if yes how to do?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through the documentation for a while and can't find an official way to actually accomplish this. However, from looking through the code I found that the user is actually logged in through a call to a function called [`set_login_sessions`](https://github.com/haseydesign/flexi-auth/blob/master/library_files/application/models/flexi_auth_model.php#L1736). The function is private to the `Flexi_auth_model` class, however.

If you're absolutely sure you wouldn't introduce any vulnerabilities you aren't already taking care of some other way, you can define your own method along the lines of:

```
public function login_3rd($identity = FALSE) {
     // Check logins, activation, suspensions etc like `Flexi_auth_model::login`

     // Confirm the login with the OAuth service

     // Query the DB to get the user

     set_login_sessions($user, FALSE);
}
```

Most of this is pretty much just like the `login` function but adjusted for 3rd party authentication.

It is important that you set the `$logged_in_via_password` argument to `FALSE` when calling `set_login_sessions`. There are some sensitive areas on a web application (like withdrawing money or something) that should require the user to have entered the password before going through. This prevents a friend who re-opens your browser (or someone who gets your session via malicious means) from having access to certain things. Flexi-auth provides a [`is_logged_in_via_password`](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/user_guide/validation_functions#is_logged_in_via_password) that allows you to check this. But it won't work if we don't tell it the truth.

Comment: Ook.. I will see it.. soon